# Freeradius Disable "marking server as dead"

Tags: proxy, freeradius, radius

```
Proxy: Marking home server 10.0.0.1 port 1812 as zombie (it has not responded in 14.000000 seconds).
Proxy: Marking home server 10.0.0.1 port 1812 as dead.
```

FreeRADIUS marks my realm server (proxy.conf) as a zombie, and later on dead. I need to debug the issue by making multiple attempts, but FreeRADIUS does not forward any requests anymore to "dead" servers. Therefore I need FreeRADIUS to stop marking anything as zombie or dead. How do I disable this?

This is my realm config:

```
realm NULL {
type = radius
authhost = 10.0.0.1:1812
accthost = 10.0.0.1:1813
secret = xxx
nostrip 
}
```